# Casting a String-ified byte array into byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following String-ified byte[]: "[0, 1, 2 , 3]".

And I would like to cast this into a byte[].
How can I do this in Java?

Comment: should the result be a byte array containing `{0, 1, 2, 3}`? In this case this is not "casting".

Comment: yes. I am trying to get that byte array. Sorry, I am not sure what word to use.

Comment: [Somewhat relatd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

Comment: Possible way: remove `'['` and `']'` from the string, split on `','` and then parse the integers obtained in this way. This will work as long as the elements in the exploded string fit a byte.

Comment: Probably the `split` method of the `String` class and the `parseByte` method of the `Byte` class would both be useful for this.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I accidentally removed your comment. I am very sorry. I was about to vote up but I don't know what I clicked and it was removed.

Comment: @Ray it was an automatic comment from flagging as duplicate, and it was removed when I closed the question. No worries.